# VS 2019 doesn't model stored procedures correctly but VS 2017 does. Is there a known difference?

Tags: visual-studio, entity-framework, stored-procedures

I have a VS 2019 solution that uses EF 6.2 (database first). When I imported a stored procedure and then configured the properties to return a complex type, the designer did not place the stored procedure object in the context of the model. You could however see the stored procedure in "Function Imports" and "Stored Procedures/Functions" of the model browser. Tried over and over.

Then, I opened the same solution in VS 2017. Dropped the stored procedure from the model browser, then imported the stored procedure again (and assigned the complex type as the return). After compiling the stored procedure object could not be found in the context of the model.

I have been able to repro this. Very odd. Not an issue of permissions because the import works in VS2017 but not VS2019. Same versions of EF in both (it's the same solution).

Comment: Here's how I can repro this: Create a solution with VS 2017, target .NET 4.6.1. Add EF 6.2. Add a database (database first). Add a table and maybe a stored procedure. Compile. Then, open the same solution with VS 2019. If I then try to add another table or stored procedure, it is displayed on the EDMX designer's surface but, even after compiling, doesn't show up in the model or entities.

Answer (score 2):

This is a bug. Read about it here: https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework6/issues/705

Until VS 16.1 released, the work around (pretty simple) is to right click on the .tt file and "Run custom tool"

Comment: I had my share of problems too with stored proc in EF, I thought this would help me but I'm stuck on another form of issue